# Day to day rolling correlations by matching name

Tags: r, dplyr, window-functions

Let us say I have the data frame below. (The data set that I have is not necessarily as small as this.)

```
library(lubridate)

x <- data.frame(
  date = c(rep(ymd(20160601), 4), rep(ymd(20160602), 3), rep(ymd(20160603), 3)),
  name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "d"),
  observation = sample(1:10)
)

#          date name observation
# 1  2016-06-01    a          10
# 2  2016-06-01    b           7
# 3  2016-06-01    c           3
# 4  2016-06-01    d           2
# 5  2016-06-02    a           8
# 6  2016-06-02    b           6
# 7  2016-06-02    c           4
# 8  2016-06-03    b           5
# 9  2016-06-03    c           1
# 10 2016-06-03    d           9
```

I want to find day to day correlation of observations of matching names, i.e., for the date 2016-06-02, I want to find the correlation between <8, 6, 4> and <10, 7, 3> because only a, b, and c are common in both 2016-06-02 and 2016-06-01. I can do this as such (there are probably better ways to do this):

```
filter(x, date %in% ymd(20160601)) %>%
  left_join(filter(x, date %in% ymd(20160602)), by = "name") %>%
  transmute(
    date = ymd(20160602),
    correlation = cor(observation.x, observation.y, use = "complete.obs")) %>%
  `[`(1, )

#         date correlation
# 1 2016-06-02   0.9966159
```

But how do I do this for the entire data frame using window functions, so that I get a data frame that consists of all dates and their correlation with the previous date? I would prefer a dplyr/RcppRoll solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` doesn't have rolling merges. Assuming you actually need one (not clear from OP, since sample data doesn't have holes), you can do:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(x) # or setDT to convert in place

dt[, date := as.Date(date)] # not very clear from OP if you have dates or datetimes
                            # let's make sure it's dates

dt[.(name = name, old.date = date - 1, obs = observation),
     on = c(name = 'name', date = 'old.date'), roll = T][
   , cor(obs, observation, use = 'pairwise.complete.obs'), by = date]
#         date         V1
#1: 2016-06-01         NA
#2: 2016-06-02  0.9966159
#3: 2016-06-03 -0.5000000
```

Comment: One more question; how would we do it without rolling merges if that is simpler?

Comment: @ZaferCesur if your data doesn't have holes, you can just `shift` your observations